# Crash when calling a JNI method in android

Tags: android

I am calling `initPath` method and get a crash, only in Samsung galaxy tab with API 16. Can any one please tell me what am I doing wrong. The method is-

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_prat_render_GLLib_initPath (JNIEnv *env,jobject obj, jstring name) {
    const char *str= (*env).GetStringUTFChars(name,0);
    FilePath::folderPath = std::string(str); //Crashes at this line
    FilePath::folderPath.c_str());
    (*env).ReleaseStringUTFChars( name, str); 
}
```

Comment: Do you have any crash log to show?

Comment: A/libc: @@@ ABORTING: INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN dlfree addr=0x5e94e454
 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 23592

Comment: Can anyone please help me out. I have added the crash log. It simply gives invalid heap address

Comment: If it's failing at address 0xdeadbaad, the VM is deliberately aborting. The logcat output immediately before the crash should have an explanation of why the VM has decided to bail.

Answer (score 0):

First, could you run it without FilePath::folderPath ? This way we can check if the problem is in JNI conversion, or when assigning to "folderPath".
Could you also log the content of "str" with __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tag", "Error msg");

Next steps would be dependent on the outcome of above check.